# Why is Alexa telling me to dial emergency services?

Tags: smart-home, alexa

When I tell Alexa to be quiet, it often, but not always, responds with this.

https://youtu.be/DZssCjoTg-0

We have our wake word set to "computer" because Star Trek. As you can see from the video, it does it most of the time, but not consistently every time. I was wondering whether it is just me, but it also does the same for my wife. Other Echo Dot units in different locations also do the same.

**Questions**

1. Why does it give this answer?
2. How can I report this to Amazon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried and my 4 devices dont do this.  On the app, you can -

- Press More Icon
- Select Activity History
- Select Voice

Here you can see your commands and what Alexa interpreted it as.    To tell it  that it erred -

- Press on the Down Arrow/Chevron
- Press on Thumbs Down to tell it, that it got it wrong.

Comment: Good suggestion! Turns out Alexa heard "fire"! I don't think I said it any differently the third time, so not sure why it is inconsistent. Thanks!

Comment: @JamesGeddes it sounds like you are saying `choir` ... there is no `T` on the end of the spoken word

Comment: @jsotola Good point! Perhaps I should annunciate a little more!

Comment: @JamesGeddes if this answer helped you, it is polite to mark it "Accepted."